# Why $\mathrm{SU}_2(\mathbb{C})/\lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace \cong \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is exceptionnal?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-isomorphism, exceptional-isomorphisms

One can prove that $\mathrm{SU}_2(\mathbb{C})/\lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace \cong \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$. But why we call this isomorphism exeptionnal? I believe that we call it exptionnal because there exist no $(n,k)\in\mathbb{N}^2$, and an homeomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathrm{SU}_n$ to $\mathrm{SO}_k$.

I found a way to explain why when $k=n+1$ (which is the case in $\mathrm{SU}_2(\mathbb{C})/\lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace \cong \mathrm{SO}_3(\mathbb{R})$) using the Lie group dimension. We show that the dimension of $\mathrm{SU}_n$ is $n^2-1$ so $n^2-1=n+1$ is only possible when $n=2$.

But, in general I don't know how to proceed. Why is it not possible for exemple between $\mathrm{SU}_3$ and $\mathrm{SO}_8$ and so on?

Any help or thought will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Do you know of the classification of simple Lie algebras? There are certain infinite series $A_n, B_n, C_n$ and $D_n$ which give rise to different Lie algebras. However, for small $n$ some of them become isomorphic, this is known as an *exceptional* isomorphism. One particular exmaple is $A_2 \simeq D_2$, which translates to $\mathfrak{su}(2) \simeq \mathfrak{so}(3)$.

Comment: No, I don't sorry, the only thing that I know concerning Lie algebras is the definition.. But ok, we have to use this theory to answer the question?

Comment: Well, you don't need to understand it in order to see that there is such an isomorphism. However, when you ask for the origin of the word *exceptional*, then this is it's origin unless I'm horribly mistaken. To give you a certain flavor of what these isomorphisms look like, note that the classification of simple Lie algebras is the same as that of so called *connected finite Dynkin diagrams*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#/media/File:Finite_Dynkin_diagrams.svg . The number in the subscript is the number of yellow dots. You can see that for low $n$ some of these coincide

Comment: More generally, an exceptional isomorphism appears when you have two families of objects whose members are generally non-isomorphic, but where an isomorphism *magically* appears between distinguished members (usually in the lower members). There is a wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_isomorphism#Lie_theory

Comment: SU(3) has a rank (dimension of maximal torus) of 2, while SO(8) has a rank of 4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_torus

Comment: Okay, thanks. But since I proved that $\mathrm{SU}_2/\lbrace \pm 1\rbrace \cong \mathrm{SO}_3$ without using any Lie Algebra theory, I was wondering if it was possible to "justify" the word exeptionnal without using it. But if I undersand you, you saying it's not, it comes from Lie Algebra classification. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the fact that this isomorphism is *exceptional* comes from the classification